Оператор SELECT для новичка
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно существует еще одно решение.
Итак, есть таблица "users" (имя, фамилия, дата рождения и вес). Необходимо вывести имя и максимальный вес человека, который был рожден начиная с 1 января 2000 года. При этом указать название столбца "Наибольший вес"

вариант 1: выводит только вес, но хотелось бы чтоб еще и имя;
SELECT MAX(weight_kg) AS "Наибольший вес" FROM users WHERE date_of_birth > "1999-12-31";

вариант 2: выдает наибольший вес, но имя самого первого пользователя, что неверно;
SELECT MAX(weight_kg) AS "Наибольший вес", firstname FROM users WHERE date_of_birth > "1999-12-31";

вариант 3: выдает верный результат, но есть ли другой способ ?
SELECT weight_kg AS "Наибольший вес", firstname FROM users WHERE date_of_birth > "1999-12-31" GROUP BY firstname ORDER BY weight_kg DESC LIMIT 1;


Заранее всем спасибо :)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

третий вариант выглядит как ответ на ваш вопрос, зачем вы ищите еще один способ? Вы забираете два столбца, выбираете значения больше заданной даты, группируете по имени и сортируете по весу, затем забираете первый. Все отлично же, нет?

Если я конечно не ошибаюсь, но MAX выдаёт максимальное значение со всего столбца. Зачем вам это? Если я правильно понял, у вас только одно значение веса хранится для каждого человека, значит его и надо просто выбрать без использования MAX. Вам одного человека нужно вывести, или нескольких? В какой-то последовательности веса? Мне кажется, вы сами не поняли, что вам нужно выбрать и вывести

@Faraday через max оформите ответ?

@Dmitry, не понял вашего вопроса. Что вам оформить?

@Dmitry да вы правы, третий вариант отлично работает, но хотелось знать возможно есть способ по-проще... В любом случае спасибо за ответ)

@Faraday мне ничего не надо, напишите ответ на вопрос, указанным вами способом.

@Dmitry, так я же ещё написал кроме этого, что я не до конца понимаю задачу, что человеку нужно вывести то, и какие у него данные хранятся в одном рекорде. Зачем он юзает max? Или это сборник нескольких таблиц через join? Или это просто название столбца? Тогда можно просто ORDER BY использовать без MAX. Что мне оформлять, если я не понимаю, что ему нужно?

@Faraday, понятно все,  не обращайте внимание

Я только не понял зачем тут вообще нужен max? Обычный select с фильтром сортировкой и выбором первой строчки отлично подходит же. SELECT weight_kg, firstname FROM users WHERE date_of_birth > "1999-12-31" ORDER BY weight_kg DESC LIMIT 1;

Необходимо вывести имя и максимальный вес человека, который был рожден начиная с 1 января 2000 года. А если максимальный вес - равный у более чем одного человека, то надо вывести их всех? одного любого? одного определённого по некоему дополнительному критерию? И ещё - какая ТОЧНО версия MySQL?

Способ упомянутый в комментариях
Тут псевдокод, подправьте на нужные значения
SELECT column, column_max_value 
FROM your_table 
WHERE column_max_value =(SELECT MAX(column_max_value) FROM your_table)
AND dates > YYYY-MM-DD;

Такой запрос возвращает все строки (если такие имеются) с максимальным значением. Следовательно можно дописать сортировку по имени и вытаскивать самого тяжелого и первого по алфавиту
Субъективный комментарий на размышление
Мне все-таки кажется, что указанный способ ТС будет лучше по двум причинам:

Понятный запрос и логика без ветвлений
БД же может индексировать максимальное значение и если таковое единично, то оно много быстрее будет отрабатывать, если необходимо забирать только первую строку. Здесь сомнения, поправьте, те, кто погружен в тему индексации БД


Но тут же получается два запроса и не учитывается диапазон дат.

@user7860670 поэтому и указан псевдокод, добавил по вашему пожеланию. Плюс это доп способ использовать аггрегатор max, а не каноническое решение, на что я указал в комментарии под вопросом и в самом ответе

@user7860670 Но тут же получается два запроса Здесь ОДИН запрос. Имеющий в своём составе подзапрос. Но думать, что подзапрос будет выполнен независимо - категорически неверно.
